# How to use passport-local and sails with hybrid application(phonegap based)

Tags: node.js, cordova, cookies, sails.js, passport.js

I am currently using sails as my webserver and have integrated passport using [sails-generate-auth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-generate-auth).

I want to use passport-local and successfully tested my login, register and method wise access control using POST calls to my server but I understand mobile based hybrid applications cannot use cookie. How do I use passport-local with mobile hybrid applications(cordova based)?

I understand login in mobile based applications is used with token based instead of cookie based. What changes do I need to make in my webserver and how can I test using a simple reset client like postman.

Currently my config/passport.js is

```
module.exports.passport = {
  local: {
    strategy: require('passport-local').Strategy
  },
};
```